# Laravel command with option (without value) is not defined

Tags: laravel

Hi I have a weird issue with passing an option to a command from another command.

**Command A**

```php
protected $signature = 'foo:bar {--internal}';
```

Command B

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class FooBaz extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'foo:baz';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = '';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->call('foo:bar --internal');
    }
}
```

Calling `foo:baz` yields

> Command "foo:bar --internal" is not defined.

While calling `foo:baz --internal` just works. Is this a bug?

Comment: I don't know, I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Did you try `$this->call('foo:bar', ['internal']);` or `$this->call('foo:bar', ['--internal']);`?

Comment: @A.Seddighi It works, if you want you can make it an answer

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands), the options can be passed as an arguments

Example:

```
$this->call('foo:bar', ['internal']);
```

Comment: However the question is still legit: docs also show an example with adding the option directly and this does currently not work: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Comment: Also still not passing the option down to FooBaz, only the error disappears....

Comment: maybe the `$this->call()` and `Artisan::call()` call the commands in differents way.